# JSR303: Is it possible to have different validation/messaging levels?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I have a requirement that some validation should throw a standard error on validation, but some fields should be validated as 'informational' and return a message to the user.  I'm trying to figure out how to do it, and it seems that groups might be a solution or creating custom validation constraint annotations.  Has anyone else encountered this and/or is able to suggest a sound design?

Thanks!

Comment: Groups feels like the way to go to me

Answer (score 1):

Such constraint severities were the original idea behind the `payload` attribute of the constraint annotation types. The [BV specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintdefinition-payload) contains the following example:

```
public class Severity {
    public static class Info implements Payload {};
    public static class Error implements Payload {};
}

public class Address {
    @NotNull(message="would be nice if we had one", payload=Severity.Info.class)
    public String getZipCode() {...}

    @NotNull(message="the city is mandatory", payload=Severity.Error.class) 
    String getCity() {...}
}
```

When you're performing the validation you could use the constraint payloads to decide which action shall be taken in case a constraint violation with a given severity occurs.